# Can not run FIJI / imagej, java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java

When I try to run fiji on Ubuntu 16.10, I get

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I'm guessing the real error is,

```
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

How do I resolve that. I'm using that Java installed

```
$ java -v
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.10.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [FAQ on Linux](https://imagej.net/Frequently_Asked_Questions#On_Linux), to run Fiji, or ImageJ, you'll need `--java-home`

Use this command on Ubuntu 16.04 (which uses java-8)

```
./ImageJ-linux64 --java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```